# python ORM for apache cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, pycassa

Which is the best python ORM based on Flask framework for Apache Cassandra 2.x?

The ORM you are sugesting, should have best features, like that of pycassa or even more. It will be most useful, if you share with examples on any URLs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my knowledge, the best supported object mapper (possibly the only one) is the cqlengine API maintained with the DataStax Python driver:

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/object_mapper.html

The core driver is always kept in parity with server features. The cqlengine API lacks some more advanced features at this time, but it's slated for more work.